# PHP -> displaying unread GMail mail

Tags: php, gmail

is there a simple customizable script that I can use to display the unread mail in a GMail account?

I don't know if I should use POP or IMAP to retrieve.

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2008/03/how-to-use-imap.html). It explains how to do it through the IMAP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know POP does not support marking emails are read. Email clients mark them after they download. All download mails are numbered to keep track. So you might need to check if there is a GMail API for that task.